# Increasing Performance in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, parallel-processing, c++14

I'm trying to create threads in C++. I certainly feel that creating threads inside a for loop doesn't means parallelism. But i want to parallelize a the below code piece of logic.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) // for each instance in the dataset
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 100000; j++) // target each other instance
    {
        if(i == j) continue;

        float distance = 0;

        for(int k = 0; k < 2000; k++)
        {
            float a = dataset->get_instance(i)->get(k)->operator float();
            float b = dataset->get_instance(j)->get(k)->operator float();
            float diff = a - b
            distance += diff * diff;
        }

        distance = distance + 10;

    }

}
```

Is there any possibility of parallelism in the above code piece? Or can anyone provide me some code example to understand a similar parallelization of threads.

Comment: Well, first of all you need to find out how many hardware cores you have. Then you need to measure and divide the work in the most effective way. So, basically try and fail until succeed.

Comment: This code doesn't appear to do anything. `distance` is declared inside the `for(j)` loop so the value is unknown outside.

Comment: @kfsone: I have updated the usage of distance outside, Can you kindly provide any pointers or give me any code logic to be result.

Comment: Well you need to first let us know what you want to parallelize. You are trying to calculate the shortest distance between two points, which does not necessaryly require parallelization.

Comment: `distance` is still only known inside the `j` loop, so the code you've added at the end of the `i` loop is invalid, and smallestDistance has the same problem. The compiler could easily elide the entire function: https://godbolt.org/g/ywcq9x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*If* none of the functions being shown have side effects, you could simply run one thread per iteration of the `i` loop, you could create N threads and divide the number of iterations of the outer `i` loop to each thread, or you could use `std::async`:

```
struct ShortestDistance {
    float distance;
    int distClass;
};

ShortestDistance inner_loop(const Dataset* dataset, int i)
{
    ShortestDistance dist { MAX_FLT, 0 };

    for(int j = 0; j < dataset->num_instances(); j++) // target each other instance
    {
        if(i == j) continue;

        float distance = 0;

        for(int k = 0; k < dataset->num_attributes() - 1; k++) // compute the distance between the two instances
        {
            float a = dataset->get_instance(i)->get(k)->operator float();
            float b = dataset->get_instance(j)->get(k)->operator float();
            float diff = a - b
            distance += diff * diff;
        }

        distance = sqrt(distance);
        if (distance < dist.distance) {
            dist.distance = distance;
            dist.distClass = dataset->get_instance(j)->get(dataset->num_attributes() - 1)->operator int32();
        }
    }

    return dist;
}

void outer_loop(const Dataset* dataset)
{
    std::vector<std::future<ShortestDistance>> vec;
    for(int i = 0; i < dataset->num_instances(); i++) // for each instance in the dataset
    {    
        vec[i] = std::async(inner_loop, dataset, i);
    }

    DistanceResult overallResult { FLT_MAX, 0 };
    for (auto&& fut : vec)
    {
        DistanceResult threadResult = fut.get();
        if (threadResult.distance < overallResult.distance)
            overallResult = threadResult);
    }
}
```